# Unauthorized error send message from function app to eventgrid with Role Based Access for Event Grid Send

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid, role-based-access-control

I have a function app with a function that sends message to event grid. A function in this same function app is subscribed to this event grid topic. I get unauthorized access to send message despite function app has set role based access for Event Grid Send.

I have set the function app Identity to System Assigned ON:

[image]

I also set the function app Assigned Role to Event Grid Sender at Subscription level (within which the event grid topic also sits):

[image]

The event grid sender role assigned is confirmed at IAM Role Assignments of the Event Grid Topic:

[image]

When I execute the function app to send data to event grid I get unauthorized error:

```
//Name of the endpoint of Event grid topic
        string topicEndpoint = transformAlgoSendRMessage_TopicEP;
        //Creating client to publish events to eventgrid topic
        EventGridPublisherClient client = new EventGridPublisherClient(new Uri(topicEndpoint), new DefaultAzureCredential());
        //Creating a sample event with Subject, Eventtype, dataVersion and data
        EventGridEvent egEvent = new EventGridEvent("TransformTelemetry", "TransformAlgorithm.broadcastTransform", "1.0", machinePartTransformTelemetry);
        // Send the event
        
        try
        {
            await client.SendEventAsync(egEvent);
            if (b_debug_contractor)
                log.LogInformation("SendRTransformMessage sent transformdata - PosX:" + machinePartTransformTelemetry[1]);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.LogError("Failed to send SendRTransformMessage. " + e.Message);
        }
```

Unauthorized Error:

```
[2022-11-25T08:00:45.646Z] Failed to send SendRTransformMessage. The principal associated with access token presented with the incoming request does not have permission to send data to /subscriptions/MySubscriptionID/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/functionappname. Report 'e9595a36-8420-4466-b91a-801fbfcf605d:4:11/25/2022 8:00:48 AM (UTC)' to our forums for assistance or raise a support ticket.
[2022-11-25T08:00:45.646Z] Status: 401 (The principal associated with access token presented with the incoming request does not have permission to send data to /subscriptions/mySubscriptionID/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/myfunctionappname. Report 'e9595a36-8420-4466-b91a-801fbfcf605d:4:11/25/2022 8:00:48 AM (UTC)' to our forums for assistance or raise a support ticket.)
[2022-11-25T08:00:45.647Z] ErrorCode: Unauthorized
[2022-11-25T08:00:45.647Z]
[2022-11-25T08:00:45.647Z] Content:
[2022-11-25T08:00:45.648Z] {
[2022-11-25T08:00:45.648Z]     "error": {
[2022-11-25T08:00:45.649Z]         "code": "Unauthorized",
[2022-11-25T08:00:45.649Z]         "message": "The principal associated with access token presented with the incoming request does not have permission to send data to /subscriptions/mySubscriptionID/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/myfunctionappname. Report 'e9595a36-8420-4466-b91a-801fbfcf605d:4:11/25/2022 8:00:48 AM (UTC)' to our forums for assistance or raise a support ticket.",
[2022-11-25T08:00:45.650Z]         "details": [{
[2022-11-25T08:00:45.650Z]             "code": "Unauthorized",
[2022-11-25T08:00:45.650Z]             "message": "The principal associated with access token presented with the incoming request does not have permission to send data to /subscriptions/mySubscriptionID/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/myfunctionappname. Report 'e9595a36-8420-4466-b91a-801fbfcf605d:4:11/25/2022 8:00:48 AM (UTC)' to our forums for assistance or raise a support ticket."
```

I note I [tried with key credentials but the Azure would not recognize the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74566777/function-app-cant-send-message-to-event-grid-the-given-key-1-was-not-present).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results***

I created one function app and enabled **system assigned identity** as below:

[image]

Add role assignment to the Event grid like below: ***Go to Azure Portal -> Event grid Topics -> Your Topic -> Access control (IAM)***

[image]

The error **`401 Unauthorized`** may occur if you selected service principal instead of **managed identity** where 'Type' is **App** not *Function App* while assigning role like below:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to select **Managed Identity** as Function App while assigning role to Event grid like below:

[image]

Select **`Review+assign`** to assign the role as below:

[image]

Role **`EventGrid Data Sender`** got assigned successfully to the Event grid like below:

[image]

This will **automatically reflect** in the function app too and no need to assign this role separately to function app identity.

To **confirm** that, ***Go to Azure Portal -> Your Function App -> Identity -> Azure role assignments***

[image]

Now restart the function app and execute the function again. If the issue still **persists**, raise a support ticket.

**Reference:**
[Send Events To Event Grid Topic Using Managed Service Identity by **Rittik Basu**](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/send-events-to-event-grid-topic-from-blob-triggered-azure-function-using-managed2/)

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Sridevi , I found the step I missed. I note in my case that after adding the role in eventgrid for the function app I had to manually add the role assignment to the function app Identity as per your last step/snapshot, meaning it didn't automatically reflect in the function app identity role assignments and else would give unauth error.